# UI less application in iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm new to mac/iOS development. I'm thinking of to develop a UI less application by using existing Apps/Libraries.

I want to know whether following things will be possible to make or not, it will be great if someone provides me some insight.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to show/hook additional buttons on existing contacts
   -> contacts view (some additional buttons under FaceTime button)?
2. Is it possible to route some messages to SMS inbox? where the user
   feels like he received/sent the real SMS?

Answer (score 3):

In short: no.

In somewhat longer: iOS applications run in a sandbox that rather severely limits their ability to interact with the outside world. This is for the purpose of protecting the user's security and experience using the device. It MIGHT be possible to accomplish both of those things if you were running on a jailbroken device and using non-public APIS (though frankly I doubt you'd be able to add buttons to the existing contacts list by any means at all). But such an app couldn't be sold in Apple's app store.